# Apache Solr: HTML inside CDATA

Tags: solr, jstl, cdata

I have a Solr XML doc with CDATA that contains HTML

ex:

```
<field name="content"><![CDATA[<p>Content is here</p>]]></field>
```

I add this doc and when i run a search....in the output the HTML tags inside of the CDATA become escaped.

```
&lt;p&gt;Content is here&lt;/p&gt;
```

I want to keep the HTML tags intact on output. is there a way to prevent this?

I'm using JSP/JSTL and this is the code used to output the field:

```
<c:out value="${content}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `<c:out value="${content}" escapeXml="false" />` or just `${content}`?

Comment: Yes, I did try -- no luck though.